# Is there a way to tell how many rows are in the SelectQuery results in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

All I really want to know is whether or not my query returned results or not, but an actual row count value would be nice.

Example:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'status'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load all your results into an array using the handy `fetchAll()` method of the query and then count the array as normal. This will result in only one query being executed:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'status'));
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

$count = count($results);

foreach ($results as $result) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Assumed there was some way to load the contents to an array :D

Answer (score 2):

You are Looking for:

[countQuery()](http://drupal.org/node/310075#count_queries)

In your example you can use:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'status'));
$num_rows=$query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
```

to count the results, and fetch them afterwards:

```
$result=$query->execute();
```

Comment: So there's no easy way to do it directly from the SelectQuery results? Really don't want to have to query the DB twice no built another query object :(

Comment: I don't think you need to build another query object - you can use the existing one after countQuery (see the edited answer), but of course, the sql is executed twice in this solution ...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more efficient try this instead.

```
$result = db_select('table_name' ,'t');
$result->fields('t')->execute();
$num_of_results = $result->rowCount();
```